# select every 6th element, starting from 8th element in a list

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have created a list where i want to select every 6th element, starting from 8th element.
Is it possible using `nth-child`, is there any hack for this using css alone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `:nth-child(6n+8)` (it's not a *hack* but a conventional feature).

For further reading: [How nth-child Works](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

---

An example of the way it'll work:

```
n = k;    (6 * k) + 8 = 6k + 8
n = 0;    (6 * 0) + 8 = 8
n = 1;    (6 * 1) + 8 = 14
n = 2;    (6 * 2) + 8 = 20
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, i'm pretty bad at math. will surely go through the link.

Comment: @italy yup, thats useful too. i got it up with the formula just the same you have printed above. :)